# Python - average word count for multiple folders

Tags: python, character, average

I have a folder with subfolders containing text files that is organized as follows:

```
corpus - french - negative - [text files]
corpus - french - positive - [text files]
corpus - german - negative - [text files]
corpus - german - positive - [text files]
```

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
import glob

files_list = glob.glob("corpus/*/*/*")

for path in files_list:
    elems = re.split("\\\\", path)
    corpus, ln, classe, nom = elems
    file = open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf", errors="ignore")
    read_file = file.read()
    words = read_file.split()
average = sum(len(word) for word in words) / len(words)
print(ln, classe, average)
```

My goal is to create a code that gives the average word count for all the text files, organized by the language and the class (positive/negative). So I want the results to look like this:

```
french negative 34.2
french positive 23.4
german negative 9.3
german positive 8.23
```

---

This is what I get from the print function: `german positive 9.416666666666666`

The files are just tweets saved under the names 1.txt, 2.txt, etc.

Comment: There is indentation issue. You want to print for every file, but you've coded to print just for the last file.

Comment: When I print for every file, it still isn't the result that I want as it lists the "average" for each individual file when I want the combined average of all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I asked my professor and implemented his suggestions to get this code which counts the total number of words (tokens) in each folder and organizes the results how I wanted them to be:

```
import glob

files_list = glob.glob("corpus/*/*/*")

dic = {}

for path in files_list:
    elems = re.split("\\\\", path)
    corpus, ln, classe, nom = elems
    file = open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf", errors="ignore")
    read_file = file.read()

    words = read_file.split(' ')

    #print(ln, classe, nom, len(words))

    dic.setdefault(ln, {})
    dic[ln].setdefault(classe, 0)

    dic[ln][classe]+=len(words)

    file.close()

print(dic)
```

This code gave this as the print:
`{'french': {'negative': 4982, 'positive': 1807}, 'german': {'negative': 25140, 'positive': 6817}}`

Since I know how many files are in each folder, I just did the averages by hand, which isn't the most automatic way to do it, but at least it got the job done.